# Delphi WideString in Visual Studio MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, delphi, mfc

I have am trying to receive information from a EXE that was written in Delphi.  The EXE passes me a pointer to one of its data structures:

```
Type
  RecordType = Record
    St:   WideString;
    Next: Pointer;
  End;

Var
  DataRec: ^RecordType;
```

So in Visual Studio MFC I have declared a data type that should be similar:

```
struct RecordRec
{
  BSTR St;
  void *Next;
};

RecordRec *DataRec;
```

The Delphi Help says that a WideString is compatible with a BSTR, however, this does not work.  When I look at my St in Debug Mode it says

```
"0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr>   wchar_t *"
```

I don't know how to declare the equivalent of a WideString in Visual Studio MFC.

If it was a ShortString I would declare:

```
struct RecordRec
{
  BYTE StLen;
  char St[255];
  void *Next;
};
```

but this does not work for a WideString and I really don't think I should declare a variable with ~2^30 (1,073,741,824) characters in it.

What am I missing?  I really hope that someone can help.

Comment: Pointer.... In whose address space? What method is used to send a pointer?

Comment: It is very complicated.  The first thing is there is a Windows Service.  The Service starts and runs automatically when Windows starts.  When the Delphi EXE runs it calls a function in a DLL that is part of the Service and passes the Service a pointer to its data.  The Visual Studio MFC program then calls a function in the Service to get a copy of the pointer.  However when it gets to my MFC program that is when I see Bad Ptr.  This all used to work when a ShortString was used, but then things were updated to a WideString and I don't know what the equivalent declaration in MFC would be.

Comment: Add all the details in the question body. They are critically important. Passing  WideString type to/from DLL is right approach, but describe all circumstances

Comment: P.S. I have control over the Service and the MFC program, but I do not have control over the Delphi EXE.

Comment: So, you have one process that is calling a DLL function, and that DLL is sending the data to another process. That means the DLL needs to *serialize* the data into a format that can be safely passed across process boundaries and then *unserialized* on the other end. A `ShortString` can be safely passed as-is, as it is a fixed-length memory block that is easily copied. But a `BSTR` cannot, it must be marshaled. Pointers are only valid in the context of the process that allocates them. You can't pass pointers across process boundaries.

Comment: @Gary Show us DLL function that is called by Delphi process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Delphi `WideString` is indeed a wrapper for a `BSTR`, however, that does not mean a raw `BSTR` pointer can be passed as-is from one process to another.  Its data has to be *marshalled* when passing across process boundaries.  COM normally handles that automatically, but passing a raw `BSTR` pointer manually does not.

So, if you can't change the Delphi app to provide an IPC-safe data block for the character data (similar to the `ShortString` workaround), then the receiving app will have to marshal the `BSTR` data manually.  It can use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) for that:

- read the `BSTR`'s length from within the Delphi app's address space (a `BSTR`'s character data is prefixed with a 4-byte integer specifying its length in `wchar_t` elements)
- allocate a `wchar_t[]` array of the specified length within its own address space
- read the character data from the Delphi app's address space into the array in its own address space.

For example (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
RecordRec *DataRec = ...;
std::wstring DataSt;

if (DataRec->St)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, TheDelphiAppProcessID);
    int len = 0;
    SIZE_T numRead = 0;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, LPBYTE(DataRec->St)-4, &len, 4, &numRead);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        DataSt.resize(len);
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, DataRec->St, &DataSt[0], len*2, &numRead);
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

// use DataSt as needed...
```

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: you are misreading that documentation. A `BSTR` is *allocated* by COM functions, using a centralized system memory manager (which is one of the reasaons why `WideString` is less efficient than `UnicodeString`), but the data itself resides in the allocating app's address space, like anything else it allocates. You can pass a `BSTR` to any function of the app that accepts a `wchar_t*` as input and the function will have direct access to the character data. The Delphi app in question is calling a DLL function, and that function is passing the data to a separate service process.

Comment: `var b: BSTR; b := SysAllocString('Test'); MessageBoxW(0, PWideChar(b), '', MB_OK); SysFreeString(b);` That code would not be able to run if the `BSTR` data wasn't available in the address space of the app process that requests to allocate the `BSTR`. It does not matter if COM is the memory manager used, just like it doesn't matter if a Delphi string is allocated with BorlandMM vs FastMM vs ScaleMM. The allocated data resides in the calling app's memory address space so it can be accessed, and is *tracked* by the memory manager so is can be freed correctly later.

Comment: If a `BSTR` resided inside of COM itself at the system layer, then marshaling would not be needed to pass a `BSTR` across process boundaries, the `BSTR` pointer could be passed as-is (like an `HWND` can).  But that is not the case, because `BSTR` pointers do not have global scope, they have process scope, like most memory allocations. Thus the need for marshaling `BSTR` data across process boundaries from one address space to another.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything. Delphi's `WideString` is indeed equivalent to `BSTR`. The value you see in the debugger is a null pointer. Delphi would treat that as an empty string; you should probably treat it the same way.

Comment: But I know on the Delphi side it is not empty.  I have been testing it and filling in a value that I expect to see on the MFC side.

Comment: Then your problem lies elsewhere. There's nothing wrong with what you've provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two different processes - Delphi one (DP) and VS one (VSP). Each has own address space, and valid pointer in the DP is not valid in VSP. That is why `<Bad Ptr>` (exception?) appears.

BTW, I've noticed that address in VSP is 64-bit. Is Delphi process 64-bit too?

You need some kind of interprocess communication ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) through shared memory.

Because you have control over the Service and the MFC program, you could save received data to named memory-mapped file in DLL, then MFC process will open it and read data.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis I see, but author writes: `EXE passes me a **pointer** to one of its data structures` and shows `^RecordType`type